# C++ template return value

Tags: c++, function, templates, types, return

I need to implement a queue that serves for any datatype T using template, and one function I need to implement is called T getFirst() which returns the value of the first node
my original approach is:

```
T getFirst(){
    T returnValue = _first->_data;
    return returnValue;
}
```

I found this does not work, if I call

```
Queue<int> q;
q.add(2);
cout << Q.getFirst() << endl;
```

output is some rubbish.
What's astonishing is that if I simplify the code to:

```
T getFirst(){
    return _first->_data;
}
```

it works!!, why ??? could someone explain. The reason I need the first approach is that later I need to implement removeFirst(), which I may need a temporary holding of data. Thanks a lot guys!!!

Comment: How on earth does `return getFirst;` compile?

Comment: sorry guys, its a typo, its been fixed now, but still, why it doesn't work!!!

Comment: We need to see the rest of your implementation... The most likely reason it doesn't work is that `_first->_data` is rubbish.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you actually want:

```
return returnValue;
```

Comment: yeah, sorry man, it's a typo, but the problem still stand for itself

Answer (score 1):

Here you have error:

```
T getFirst(){
   T returnValue = _first->_data;
   return getFirst;  //^^^You return function name? 
}
```

should be

```
T getFirst(){
   T returnValue = _first->_data;
   return returnValue ;
}
```